# Image editor to check selection size, location

Tags: images

I'm looking for image editor which is capable of

1. show coordinates of mouse position in real time
2. show size of rectangular selection
3. show position of rectangular selection (top left coordinates, top right or whatsoever)
4. layer mask
5. undo history

I've tried Photoshop, Paint.Net, Krita, Firealpaca. I thought those were quite basic features so I could find suitable program very soon. Apparently I was wrong.

What those programs lacks.

Photoshop - 3

Paint.Net - 4

Krita   - 1

Alpaca - 3, 5

I'll really appreciate recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't go wrong with [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/)

Real-time mouse coordinates are on the status bar, you can view the coordinates and size of the selection box (and even adjust it's size and origin after selection) from the rectangle Select Tool Options pane (plus set fixed selection size and several other options), work with layer masks, and set the minimum number of undo levels (GIMP will retain undo all history until it reaches the amount you set in preferences).

I love GIMP. It's free and it works on Windows and Linux.

Comment: Can't believe I was so stupid. I've heard about GIMP many times, but somehow I thought it's for Linux. I've just installed GIMP. I really really appreciate your help!

Comment: Sure, no problem. There are a bunch of plugins, too.There's even a batch mode script to let you run macros against many files instead of one at a time.

Comment: I've been using it, and I'm really really satisfied with this program. :) Just a small question. When I open multiple images, previews of those images is displayed at the top of the image frame. I wonder If I can change locations of those previews. e.g. I open a,b,c files, then I want for preview of the c to be located before a, b. Is it possible? I tried to drag and drop, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: You should be able to. When you click, wait for a second, them move the preview slowly. You should see a corner outlined on the upper left hand side. Drag that between two previews or to the outside of an end preview and drop it.